# istanbul test coverage recursively @NodeJS

Tags: node.js, istanbul

I am using istanbul module for test coverage. But It's covering test cases written under test directory. How do I make it recursive so that it will cover sub directory also.

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for a recursive option in your test framework.
For exemple, if you're using Mocha, try this command:

```
istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --recursive
```